# Why does my SQL database login authentication fail?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have created online shopping website in Visual Studio with SQL database connection and I have made login and signup pages connected to index page with link button. If the user is signed in show the username and show log out button. If the user is not logged in so show signup button.

But after I have created 1 user with password then went to login page it worked but after creating the 2nd user with password, the login page always show incorrect password while ever info is correct because I have checked in SQL database the 2nd user is registered but still not signing in login page.
these are my login and sign up codes:

This is my login code

```
    protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        string query = "select * from TableUser where Username=@username AND Password=@password ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text.Trim());

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (count == 1)
        {

            Session["username"] = txtusername.Text;
            Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Your Password and Username are Incorrect !!");
        }

    }
```

and this my sign up code:

```
    protected void btnsignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        string query = "insert into TableUser ([Username], [Password],[Email],[Address],[Phone]) values(@username,@password,@email,@address,@phone)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtphone.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        txtusername.Text = "";
        txtpassword.Text = "";
        txtemail.Text = "";
        txtaddress.Text = "";
        txtphone.Text = "";

        Session["username"] = txtusername.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
```

and this is my master page code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["username"] != null)
        {

            Label1.Text = "Welcome" + Session["username"].ToString();
            LinkButton1.Visible = true;

            LinkButton2.Visible = false;
        }

        else
        {
            LinkButton1.Visible = false;
            LinkButton2.Visible = true;
        }

    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }

    protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
```

[image: these the prove, that only user John is working but not basit even thought I am entering the correct username and password]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please read the documentation for [`ExecuteScalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar). It doesn't return what you think it does. Or your query is wrong.

Comment: what do you mean , can you suggest me a solution please ?

Comment: my query is correct and worked with the first user ,

Comment: unrelated to your current problem, but you should be salting and hashing your passwords.

Comment: ExecuteScaler returns a scalar i.e. a single value, NOT a row set

Comment: Try select count(*) instead of select *

Comment: And [don't use addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: It is not recommended to use a credential (username and password) in the connection string where you have to add each user access to the database.  Recommended method is to create a group account in windows and give the database the windows credential.  Then add user to the group.  This allows users on remote machines access to the database provided the group account is on local and remote machine.  If your company uses Group Policy than the Group Policy can be the credential for the database.  The in connection string instead of user name/password use : Integrated Security=true;

Comment: Thanks guys , that really helped me a lot to understand more about it. and I have used select count(*) thanks to @Martheen it worked. in addition, I m just learning how to make online shopping site in visual studio and i will get into these advance coding by time .

Comment: Please read https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing before you continue making anything that involves user's password